# Openssl - Unable to set specific TLS version to be used when using libssl (C++)

Tags: c++, c, ssl, openssl

I want to connect to a server using only a specific TLS version while using openssl lib 1.1.1k in C++. Here is a snippet of my client code where I try to achieve this:

```
        m_sslContext = SSL_CTX_new(TLSv1_2_client_method());
        if(!m_sslContext) {
            return -1;
        }

        int ret = SSL_CTX_set_min_proto_version(m_sslContext, TLS1_2_VERSION);
        LOG(INFO, "[SSL] Setting min proto version- ", ret);

        ret = SSL_CTX_set_max_proto_version(m_sslContext, TLS1_2_VERSION);
        LOG(INFO, "[SSL] Setting max proto version- ", ret);

        LOG(INFO, "[SSL] Using SSL VERSION - ", SSL_CTX_get_min_proto_version(m_sslContext));
        LOG(INFO, "[SSL] Using SSL VERSION - ", SSL_CTX_get_max_proto_version(m_sslContext));
```

The output of this snippet is as follows:

```
20220829-13:21:40.279623591 INFO: [SSL] Setting min proto version- 1
20220829-13:21:40.279624064 INFO: [SSL] Setting max proto version- 1
20220829-13:21:40.279624191 INFO: [SSL] Using SSL VERSION - 0
20220829-13:21:40.279624544 INFO: [SSL] Using SSL VERSION - 0
```

Not sure what is wrong here. The connection established uses TLS1.3:

```
* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
```

It does support TLS1.2 since openssl command:

```
openssl s_client -tls1_2 -cipher AES128-SHA -connect host:ip
```

The openssl lib has been compiled with TLS1.2 support. Can anyone help me to figure out what's going on here?
Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
Some more information. I tried printing the SSL version being used by using - `SSL_get_version()`  and it says -

```
[SSL] Using SSL VERSION - TLSv1.2
```

But the final connection still uses TLS1.3. Another point here is that I am making an HTTP1.1/2 connection.

Comment: *"Getters return 0 in case ctx or ssl have been configured to automatically use the lowest or highest version supported by the library."*

Comment: Yes but setter returns 1 which means it should be set to TLS 1.2, right?

Comment: Just for kicks, fire the getter and see if it (a) returns zero, and (b) returns TLS1_3_VERSION. This is... weird.

Comment: It returns 0. I have logged it in the code

Comment: please create a [mre]

Answer (score 0):

```
    m_sslContext = SSL_CTX_new(TLSv1_2_client_method());
```

`TLSv1_2_client_method` is deprecated, and with appropriate compile flags it also says so (and the documentation says this too):

```
x.c:9:5: warning: ‘TLSv1_2_client_method’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
    9 |     m_sslContext = SSL_CTX_new(TLSv1_2_client_method());
```

When instead `TLS_client_method` is used then the compile warnings vanish and the code does the expected:

```
[SSL] Setting min proto version- 1
[SSL] Setting max proto version- 1
[SSL] Using SSL VERSION - 771
[SSL] Using SSL VERSION - 771
```

But why it fails with `TLSv1_2_client_method`? Looking into the source one finally ends up with `ssl_set_version_bound` in ssl/statem/statem_lib.c which contains the leading comment:

```
 * ssl_set_version_bound - set an upper or lower bound on the supported (D)TLS
 * protocols, provided the initial (D)TLS method is version-flexible.  This
 * function sanity-checks the proposed value and makes sure the method is
 * version-flexible, then sets the limit if all is well.
```

`TLSv1_2_client_method` is obviously not version-flexible, so the function has no effect here. But why it returns success? Also explained in the comments:

```
 * We ignore attempts to set bounds on version-inflexible methods,
 * returning success.
```